# Mysql databses need to copy across the servers in linux.

Tags: mysql, linux

I have two servers each having mysql version 5.1 on it, in both the server has different databases. Now i am in need of copy one database from one server to another. What is the possible way to transfer mysql databases from one to another

NOTE: i am able to perform scp copy operation in both the nodes.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Use mysql dump.

`$ mysqldump -u root -p DatabaseName > database_name_backup.sql`

scp the database down from one server and up to another 

`$ mysql -u root -p DatabaseName < database_name_backup.sql`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Do that (**user is "root" by default**):

```
mysqldump -u user -p dbname > backup.sql
```

After import it in other server.

If you have more database do:

```
mysqldump -u user -p --databases db_name1 db_name2 db_name3 > backupsomedb.sql
```

OR that for all database

```
mysqldump -u user -p --all-databases > alldatabasebackup.sql
```

If you want to save only one table

```
mysqldump -u user -p db_name table_name > backup.sql
```

Comment: I need only few databases, not all the databases from that.

Comment: @sabarish see now